# Como pegar item especifico No laravel blade

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

Como faço para pegar um item especifico no ***Laravel blade***?

Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id = 1;
    $('body').append('{{ $projeto->'+id+'->name}}'
})
```

---

```
<body>
   Deve Aparecer aqui o nome do projeto
</body>
```

Comment: Tem que adicionar um ) no append

Comment: Você não tem que acessar o blade, você tem que acessar o html gerado ... o que precisa acessar, o que esse blade gera?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas se quiser passar o nome do projeto que está configurado no arquivo .ENV do Laravel basta utilizar o helper:

{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}

Insira isso em qualquer parte da sua view blade

Para configurar o nome do projeto, vá na raiz do projeto e abra o arquivo .ENV a primeira linha será "APP_NAME", se for necessário altere essa linha para o que desejar e automaticamente aparecerá na sua view.

Abc